# Not Getting Internet On Wi-Fi Network

Tags: 8.1, wifi, lumia-icon

When I connect my phone to Network-A, it gets internet just fine. But when I connect it to Network-B, I don't get internet from it. The strange thing is that it does not say "Limited", and every other device I have can get internet from it just fine. I have tried toggling Wi-Fi on and off, deleting the connection, and restarting my phone. Has anyone else run into this and figured out how to fix it? (And I am *not* into resetting my phone ;)

Comment: Are other lumia devices able to access internet through that network? if so then there is problem with your device. If not then there is problem with router. Try resetting the router.

Comment: @AnupSharma Yes, they are. But I'm still curious as to why it has no problem with other networks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should reset the router first. If that doesn't work, then check if the router is filtering connections based on mac address(I doubt this to be any case related to yours). So if this doesn't work then check if you are using manual settings(like IP address) for your Mobile WiFi setting.Even if that doesn't work then try resetting your phone.